# Typhoon - Get instance instead of definition

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

I am using typhoon with plist integration. In one assembly, I need to create a instance that has an initializer like this:
`@selector(initWithBundleURL:moduleProvider:launchOptions:)`
The second param `moduleProvider:` takes a block and that block returns an array of objects. I want to use typhoon to inject each objects in that array.

```
- (RCTBridge *)bridgeWithModule1:(Module1 *)module1 module2:(Module2 *)module2 {
return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[RCTBridge class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
    [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithBundleURL:moduleProvider:launchOptions:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {

        [initializer injectParameterWith:url];

        RCTBridgeModuleProviderBlock block = ^NSArray *() {
            return @[module1, module2];
        };
        [initializer injectParameterWith:block];

        [initializer injectParameterWith:nil];
    }];

    definition.scope = TyphoonScopeLazySingleton;
}];
}
```

The code above doesn't work. Because `module1` and `module2` are `TyphoonDefinition` at runtime instead of real instance. Is there any way to use typhoon to inject real instances?

Answer (score 1):

With Typhoon, you can use your assembly interfaces with [run-time arguments](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Types-of-Injections#injection-with-run-time-arguments) to mix static and run-time dependencies. This avoids the boilerplate of creating custom factory classes. However, [because of the way Typhoon works](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/TyphoonAssembly) you can't modify the run-time arguments within a definition.

If you need to do this, create a custom factory class.

- [Inject the TyphoonAssembly](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself) into your custom class, to provide the object being build with static dependencies.
- The factory method will be like the one that you defined on your assembly interface. Mix the static dependencies with run-time arguments, and return the build object.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I've solved my problem by injecting the TyphoonAssembly to custom class.